# Floating Action Button has no padding despite app:useCompatPadding="true"

Tags: android, floating-action-button

For the layout in one of my activities, I have a floating action button on the bottom right. But for some reason, there is no padding on the margins for the button despite setting `app:useCompatPadding="true"`.

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_class_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:useCompatPadding="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is an image of the layout:
[image]

Some help would be appriecated, thanks!

Comment: A simple margin tag would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/add_class_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:useCompatPadding="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are not providing margin to it. This should work

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:contentDescription="@string/menu_compose"
    android:id="@+id/add_class_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will work for you.

Use as given below

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            app:rippleColor="#dadada"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_image" />
```